# TKinter wont navigate to a folder in Python (Linux)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I made a Text Editor using Python in Windows. I used `tkinter` for the GUI.

This is the snippet that loads the icon from the favicon folder from my PC. The whole code is [here](https://github.com/Nova-Striker/Open-Palm/blob/master/MainUI.py)

```
window.iconbitmap(tk.PhotoImage(r'C:\Users\Asus\Documents\GitHub\Open-Palm\favicon\favicon.ico'))
```

It works fine in Windows but recently I switched to Ubuntu , cloned the repository in home directory.

Therefore , I had to change the directory to :

```
window.iconbitmap(tk.PhotoImage(r'/home/linux/Desktop/Open-Palm/favicon/favicon.ico'))
```

But now, the `.ico` does not load and I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linux/Desktop/Open-Palm/MainUI.py", line 159, in <module>
    window.iconbitmap(tk.PhotoImage(r'/home/linux/Desktop/Open-Palm/favicon/favicon.ico'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2071, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "/home/linux/Desktop/Open-Palm/favicon/favicon.ico" not defined
```

Someone might say that I might have made an error in entering the folder location. This is the screenshot

[image: pic1]

Comment: On linux, try using  iconphoto rather than iconbitmap.

Comment: You cannot use `.ico` file in Linux, try using `.xbm` instead.  Or use `iconphoto()` to use PNG image as the icon.

Comment: @acw1668 , I got this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linux/Desktop/Open-Palm/MainUI.py", line 159, in <module>
    window.iconphoto(tk.PhotoImage(r'/home/linux/Desktop/Open-Palm/favicon/favicon-16x16.png'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2116, in wm_iconphoto
    self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, "-default", *args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm iconphoto window ?-default? image1 ?image2 ...?"`

Comment: Use `window.iconphoto(True, tk.PhotoImage(...))` instead.